# Error while uploading data using requests.post and json

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to upload a csv file using requests.post function in python. I convert the csv file to string so that i can use JSON to upload the data on the url. But when I try to post the data I get an error saying:

> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
>
> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Can someone please tell me what I can do to solve this issue?

```
data_csv = data.to_string()

type(data_csv)

results = {}

for xm in [True, False]:
results[xm] = requests.post(url_base + 'estimator',  
                            headers = api_header, proxies=proxyDict,
                               json = {'data_csv': {'csv': data_csv},
                                       'clearing_currency': 'EUR',
                                       'is_cross_margined': xm}).json()

print('Example of margin output:')

print(json.dumps(results[False]['portfolio_margin'], indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: whats the output of ``` print results[False]```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should write:

```
   import json
   requests.post(url_base + 'estimator',  
                 headers = api_header, proxies=proxyDict,
                 data = json.dumps({'data_csv': {'csv': data_csv},
                                    'clearing_currency': 'EUR',
                                    'is_cross_margined': xm}))
```

Comment: Well it was a rather stupid error. The string format of my data was incorrect, so it was throwing up this error. Once I sorted it out, the code I provided worked perfectly